# Create a function in Pythons that returns the integer in that list that has the greatest number of factors as well as the number of factors

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create a function in Python3 that accepts a list of integers and returns the integer in that list that has the greatest number of factors as well as the number of factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def number_with_max_factors(given_list):
   store_dict ={}
   for number in given_list:
      factors = []
      for j in range(1, number + 1):
         if number % j == 0:
             factors.append(j)
      store_dict.update({number:factors})
   number,factor_list = max(store_dict.items(),key =lambda x:len(x[1]))
   return number,factor_list

number, factor_list =  number_with_max_factors(given_list)
```

Will this work ?

It will return the number from the list which has maximum number of factors. I didn't understand what do you mean by greatest number of factors as well as the number of factors.

Comment: Using the Factor function                                                                                              
def factors(n):
   for i in range(1, n + 1):
       if n % i == 0:
           print(i)
n = int(input("Please enter of number: "))
factors(n)

Comment: solve this problem: write a function called MostComposite that accepts a list of integers (you can assume only positive integers and you can hard code the function input) and returns the integer in that list that has the greatest number of factors as well as the number of factors. Examples (the output does not need to replicate this exactly): MostComposite ([13,16,25,34]) => 16, 5 factors MostComposite (range(1,40)) => 36, 9 factors